# EF6 MySQL StrongTypingException The value for column IsPrimaryKey in table TableDetails is DBNull

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

We are using MySql and Entity FrameWork with VS 2015.

We have imported the necessary libraries into the project MySQLWeb, MySQL.Data, Mysql.Data.Emtity.EF6.

The problem I have is that when I create the ADO.net Entity Data Model then facing the following error. Can anyone please guide?

Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:

> 'System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column
>   'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.TableDetailsRow.get_IsPrimaryKey()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.TableDetailsRow.get_IsPrimaryKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateProperties(IList`1
>   columns, IList`1 errors, List`1& keyColumns, List`1& excludedColumns,
>   List`1& invalidKeyTypeColumns)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntityType(IList`1
>   columns, Boolean& needsDefiningQuery)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntitySets(IEnumerable`1
>   tableDetailsRows, EntityRegister entityRegister, IList`1
>   entitySetsForReadOnlyEntityTypes, DbObjectType objectType)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntitySets(IEnumerable`1
>   tableDetailsRowsForTables, IEnumerable`1 tableDetailsRowsForViews,
>   EntityRegister entityRegister)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.Build(StoreSchemaDetails
>   storeSchemaDetails)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1
>   errors)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String
>   storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings
>   settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext
>   hostContext)'.

Comment: See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163

Comment: I see this is unanswered after a year. But in case someone comes to this I am posting this [link to another question which worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575109/mysql-entity-the-value-for-column-isprimarykey-in-table-tabledetails-is).