# MySQL - Entity : The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using **Visual Studio 2013** with **Entity Framework 5** and M**ySQL Server 5.7.9**.

When trying to create a Model from the database (*or 'Update Model From Database'*) the following message appears:

> 'System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column
>   'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull . ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I know that this question has been asked before, but i haven't find any solution.
Also i don't have the option of downgrading to MySQL 5.6.

The problem occurs even for a simple table.

The sample table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If the table consists only from the Primary Key then the model is being created as it should.

**EDIT:**
If i make both the fields PRIMARY Keys the model is being created without any errors.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Kind Regards.

The full error stack:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:
>   'System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column
>   'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.TableDetailsRow.get_IsPrimaryKey()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.TableDetailsRow.get_IsPrimaryKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateProperties(IList`1
>   columns, IList`1 errors, List`1& keyColumns, List`1& excludedColumns,
>   List`1& invalidKeyTypeColumns)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntityType(IList`1
>   columns, Boolean& needsDefiningQuery)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntitySets(IEnumerable`1
>   tableDetailsRows, EntityRegister entityRegister, IList`1
>   entitySetsForReadOnlyEntityTypes, DbObjectType objectType)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.CreateEntitySets(IEnumerable`1
>   tableDetailsRowsForTables, IEnumerable`1 tableDetailsRowsForViews,
>   EntityRegister entityRegister)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.StoreModelBuilder.Build(StoreSchemaDetails
>   storeSchemaDetails)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1
>   errors)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String
>   storeModelNamespace, List`1 errors)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(EdmxHelper
>   edmxHelper)'. Loading metadata from the database took
>   00:00:00.5856317.

Comment: Try changing int(11) to BIGINT or just INT.  .Net will map the mysql types to .Net data types, and in .Net there is no INT(11), that could be breaking entity framework.  Also upgrade to EF6 if you can, it has better mysql support.

Comment: Chaning the ID's type makes no difference.
If i leave only one column (even if it is INT(10) ), the model is created sucesfully.

Regarding EF6 - i have problems in using it. VS complains about not finding the appropriate connector.

Comment: EF6 returns the same error...

Comment: Are you doing EF code first or database first?

Comment: Hi.. please refer here : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163
A workaround has been provided, although i haven't tested it yet.
Quote:
Run the following command on the MySQL DB.

set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Entity Framework (version 6.1.3) and MySQL Server (>= 5.7.6)

One way to resolve the issue is,

```
1. Open Services (services.msc) and restart MySQL57 service.
2. Execute the following commands in MySQL.
   use <<database name>>;
   set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
3. Update the .edmx.
```

It's a late reply. But hope it will help somebody.

Thanks.

Comment: This fixed the error I was receiving, I updated any new tables I wanted to add and now the tables originally there are erroring:

> Entity type 'tbl_name' is not mapped

any suggestions?

Comment: @KyleE4K, sorry I never faced such issue. When I update the .edmx file, the new tables and modified tables get updated properly.

Comment: I had to delete them all and re-update them! That fixed the mapping issue :)

Comment: Hello..this fixed my issue..But it would be nice if you could also explain your answer for why this worked.

Comment: Great it works also when creating the Model from the BD.... I agree with @Abhishek, will be nice to understend what happend under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, I code but not an expert on internal process. I was trying many ways and this method worked. I would appreciate any explanation on this method. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio 2017 when trying to create the model from database.

Comment: Works with Visual Studio 2015, MSQL 5.7.9, EF 6 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: I had to reboot Visual Studio before updating the EDMX. But it is working!

Comment: I am sure this will work. But Kindly tell me what is the impact of this script in whole database. Would it work fine ?

Answer (score 23):

This is a know bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163

Run the command on mysql console:

> set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'

OR

> set @@optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF'

(this one worked for me)

Verify that the change is effective with this command:

> SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html

Comment: It is VERY important to run this from the MySQL Console and not the Workbench. I speak from hours of experience. :(

Comment: Worked from Workbench 6.3 against MySQL v5.7.18

Comment: Worked perfectly but was reset every time I restarted my computer. Took your solution and entered Options File in the Workbench and added "derived_merge=off" in the optimizer_switch field in the Performance tab. Works after restart now.

Answer (score 9):

Every answer above works fine, but when the server or dev-machine is restarted, we need to make all steps again and again.
To solve completely, we can put this attibute 'derived_merge=OFF' in the mysql configuration.
Ok, to do that, you need to access your MySQL server with de MySQL Workbench, and open "Option File" > Select Performance tab. In Optimizer group, look for optimizer_switch, click the checkbox to enable a field, and put 'derived_merge=OFF'.
Restart your server in services.msc and voilá!

Answer (score 5):

The workaround 
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';

Answer (score 5):

The following sql worked for me:

```
use adventureworks;
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';

select @@optimizer_switch;
select @@GLOBAL.optimizer_switch;
```

My MySQL version is 5.7.15 and I used "EF Designer From Database" option from Visual Studio 2015.

I hope it helps others :)

Answer (score 2):

The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull

That's what happens when you try to use MySql among with Entity Framework.

I have solved this way:

Open MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client, type your password, press enter and then type:

```
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';

select @@optimizer_switch;
select @@GLOBAL.optimizer_switch;
```

Reboot Visual Studio you're good to go, I've tried with VS 2013 and VS 2017, and worked in both!

Comment: Felipe..
1. You provided the same answer as many others have.
2. You write in spanish (?) and most of us cannot understand.

Answer (score 1):

We've encountered same error.
But,I think this is MySQL's server problem.

### status:

- EF5
- MySQL VS Tools 1.2.5
- VS community 2015
- C#
- from Database create EF Designer(I'm using japanese edition,so menu name is my english...)

### result:

- MySQL 5.7.9 => error.
- MySQL 5.6.26 => no error.

Comment: Yes, it is a MySQL error. See my post below. I have declared it as a bug.

Comment: To prevent any update to Mysql Server, disable automatic catalog update in the Community Installer settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

Modules Used:

Entity Framework 6
MySql Data Connector 6.9.9
MySQL VS Tools 1.2.6
EF6 Tools for VS2015

I have to do this => SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
But if loggin with "root" user the error continues. When loggin with "common" user, it create the model OK.

Answer (score 1):

Run this script, it worked perfectly for me while using `MySql.Data.Entity` nugget package

```
use YourDB;
   set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
```

Answer (score 0):

From today, this is a verified **MySql Community Server 5.7.9** bug with ID [79163](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163).

As a workaround, i reshaped the application to use **Code First** practise

> (*ADO.NET Entity Data Object -> Empty Code First model*)

and manually added all the objects and their properties.

Modules Used:

- Entity Framework 6
- MySql Data Connector 6.8.9
- MySQL VS Tools 1.2.5
- EF6 Tools for VS2013

Answer (score 0):

i have found a good workaround for this type of  error.

**1. Solution ( database first)**
Instead of trying to update the existing model in the .edmx File, right-click one of your entities in edmx and choose -> go to modelbrowser ( a new register appears in the project map explorer).
Now choose the entity you want to update , right-click and do the update. In my case it worked every time without the need to switch anything off in mysql. But it may happen that you will be forced to change some relationships manually. 
If anything gets wrong here ( in my case there are no problems with non fk / pk key. If you delete a fk and try to order all relationsships by yourself your db might be dropped. But this never occures if you just update not primary / foreign key  attributes or just adding a new table. 


***EDIT:*** This Solution works great for deleting, updating and adding new relations. It causes problems when updates are performed on fk /pk attributes!

If your table has been dropped so just create a new one with same preferences.

**2. Solution (database first, when pk / fk keys must be updated)**
drop the table and create a new one. This takes 3 min all together

I hope i could help a little bit, this bug drove me crazy the past 2 weeks !

p.s. i did never experienced this type of bug until i have overwritten! a foreign key in an existing relation in mysql. Then i tried to update the relation with entity framework (database first) and since then on the dbNullBug appeared. I was able to manage my entities manually by adding and removing existing attributes but it was really exhausting. The solution 1 works well for me and if i need to update foreign key i just drop the existing Model and create a new one.