# Use MySQL and Entity Framework 6 StrongTypingException error

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have some troubles to use Entity Framework 6 and MySQL. I use Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework6.

After I click finish button on this wizard window:

[image]

I get this error window:

[image]

Why do I get error above, and how can I fix it? I don't have a table named 'TableDetails'.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575109/mysql-entity-the-value-for-column-isprimarykey-in-table-tabledetails-is

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework (version 6.1.3) and MySQL Server (5.7)

1. Open Services (services.msc) and restart MySQL57 service.
2. Execute the following commands in MySQL.
   use <>;
   set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
3. Update the .edmx.

I hope this will work for u.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **CodeCaster** I found solution in forum he referenced in comment above.

Use this command in MySQL command line client:

```
use <<database name>>;
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
```