# Turning on and off Switchable optimizations

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, command-line, visual-studio-community

I have to turn off derived_merge optimization flag because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422569/3402095), so I do it like from the link above:

```
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
```

but also I would like to check its current value... How can I do that through the command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just found it in [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html) :)

Here is how you do it:

```
mysql> SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G
```