# Generating database from model fails in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I don't know if this is another EF6 bugs when it comes to MySQL database. I am on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017. Also I am using mysql .net connector 6.9.9, and Entity Framework 6.0.0

After I have experienced [a bug with generating a model from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33575109/3402095) (with a `'derived_merge=off'`) workaround, I tried to do vice-versa thing (even if workaround helped), just to see what will happen. And it didn't work. I have created a model, and right-clicked on working space, and have chosen : Generate Database From Model button.

And I got this:

[image: error image]

Now, is it me, or is it a bug ? It would be really sad that a crucial EF6 feature doesn't work...

This is what I have in `App.config` related to Entity Framework:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

And here is the list of references:

[image: references]

Comment: Do you have the MySQL provider entry in the application config file as per the error message?

Comment: I will update my question, just a sec @DavidG

Comment: @DavidG I added it. Please check it out now.

Comment: Looks ok. Is the EF code in a different project to the config file perhaps?

Comment: Hm, EF code? There is no any code so far. I just created a model in a Designer and tried to create a database from model. @DavidG

Comment: Well the EF model then.

Comment: I don't know if I really get what you are asking, but if you ask is the `EF` model in the same project as the `App.config` I've posted above, then answer is - yes. @DavidG